# How to place a loop within another loop?

Tags: wp-query, loop

I have two loops setup using WP_Query: `$latest` and `$popular` that I'm working to setup in this example layout:

**Latest**                                     **Popular**

[image]

**Example HTML Output**

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="posts latest">
        <post1>    
        <post2>
    </div>

    <div class="posts popular">
        <post10>    
        <post9>
        <post8>    
        <post7>
    </div>

    <div class="ad-block">
        <ad>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="content">

    <div class="posts latest">
        <post3>    
        <post4>
    </div>

    <div class="posts popular">
        <post6>    
        <post5>
        <post4>    
        <post3>
    </div>

    <div class="ad-block">
        <ad>
    </div>

</div>

[...]
```

Simply put: the **Latests** and **Popular** post divs are floated next to eachother and broken apart every few posts to accommodate an full width ad block.

**My Loop**

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="posts latest">

        <?php

        $args1 = array (
            'posts_per_page'    => 1000000,
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'orderby'           => 'date'

        );

        $latest = new WP_Query( $args1 );

        if ( $latest -> have_posts() ) :

            $count = 0;

            while ( $latest -> have_posts() ) : $latest -> the_post();

                $count++;

                if ( $count % 5 == 0 ) :

                        get_template_part( 'template', 'post' ); ?>

                        </div> <!--/posts-latest-->

                        <div class="posts popular">

                            <?php

                            $args2 = array (
                                'posts_per_page'    => 10,
                                'order'             => 'ASC',
                                'orderby'           => 'date',
                            );

                            $popular = new WP_Query( $args2 );

                            if ( $popular -> have_posts() ) :

                                while ( $popular -> have_posts() ) : $popular -> the_post();

                                    get_template_part( 'template', 'post' );

                                endwhile;

                            endif;

                            ?>

                        </div> <!--/posts-popular-->

                        <div class="ad-block">
                            <?php get_template_part( 'template', 'ad' ); ?>
                        </div>

                    </div><!--/content-->    

                    <div class="content">

                        <div class="posts latest">

                <?php

                else :

                    get_template_part( 'template', 'post' );

                endif;

            endwhile;

        endif; wp_reset_postdata();

        ?>

    </div> <!--/posts-latest-->    

</div>
```

Right now this is setup so that every 5th posts in the `$latest` loop the `$popular` loop and a ad-block are added.

I understand why this doesn't work... Because every 5th post when the `$popular` loop is called it's starting again instead of continuing in order.

Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Comment: You should probably use [`$offset` parameter in your `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters) but at `1000000` posts per page I'm not sure how to add it in in a meaningful way...

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Hey thanks for the tip. I'll read over that now. My goal with the large posts_per_page value is just to have all applicable posts be shown without any pagination - I knew it was a bit of a hack.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee `$offset` looks promising for sure. If I set `posts_per_page` on the popular loop to 10 and set and dynamicly set the value for `$offset` equal to how ever many posts have already been rendered I'm thinking that should work. Now just need to workout how I can accomplish that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: We declare an incrementer at the top of our outter loop called `$popularLoop` to keep track of how many popular loops we've been through, we assume we're going to at least hit 1.

Inside our Inner Loop (popular) we need to set how many posts per page we're going to load, multiple that by how many popular loops we've been through and that is going to give us our offset. At the end of our Inner Loop we increment `$popularLoop` so our offset stays consistent:

```
<div class="content">

    <div class="posts latest">

        <?php

        $args1 = array (
            'posts_per_page'    => 1000000,
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'orderby'           => 'date'

        );

        $latest = new WP_Query( $args1 );
        $popularLoop = 0;

        if ( $latest -> have_posts() ) :

            $count = 0;

            while ( $latest -> have_posts() ) : $latest -> the_post();

                $count++;

                if ( $count % 5 == 0 ) :

                        get_template_part( 'template', 'post' ); ?>

                        </div> <!--/posts-latest-->

                        <div class="posts popular">

                            <?php
                            $popular_ppp = 10;
                            $popularOffset = $popular_ppp * $popularLoop;
                            $args2 = array (
                                'posts_per_page'    => $popular_ppp,
                                'offset'            => $popularOffset,
                                'order'             => 'ASC',
                                'orderby'           => 'date',
                            );

                            $popular = new WP_Query( $args2 );

                            if ( $popular -> have_posts() ) :

                                while ( $popular -> have_posts() ) : $popular -> the_post();

                                    get_template_part( 'template', 'post' );

                                endwhile;

                              $popularLoop++;
                            endif;

                            ?>

                        </div> <!--/posts-popular-->

                        <div class="ad-block">
                            <?php get_template_part( 'template', 'ad' ); ?>
                        </div>

                    </div><!--/content-->    

                    <div class="content">

                        <div class="posts latest">

                <?php

                else :

                    get_template_part( 'template', 'post' );

                endif;

            endwhile;

        endif; wp_reset_postdata();

        ?>

    </div> <!--/posts-latest-->    

</div>
```

Comment: Very nice. I started to do something somewhat similar using the existing `$count` variable but this approach looks a lot better. The only problem I'm having with it is that it starts counting at post 11.

Comment: whoops, `$popularLoop` should start at 0 instead of 1 (so that the offset is 0 when it hits the multiplication the first time).

Comment: Works perfectly. I'd have spent all day trying to figure this one out without your help. Seriously.. Thanks man!